# supercluster in folium map

Tags: leaflet, folium

Folium is the python wrapper of leaflet.

It is possible in folium as well in leaflet to use **markercluster** when the number of gps grows.

But markercluster have a limit of **50k** gps , recently i found that the owner of leaflet have created another clustring algorithme for huge spatial data called **supercluster** that can handle 6 millions of gps.

my question is:
 Is it possible to use the leaflet supercluster on folium maps ? 
 if yes how to use it on folium  ?